# cloud functions - export from .TS to .JS index

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My project cloud functions are built-in javascript and I've decided to slowly migrate it to typescript file by file.

I'm trying to export my onCall function from a TypeScript file on my index.js to firebase cloud functions but I keep receiving the following error into the terminal
***"Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './business'"*** when trying to deploy and not being able to properly import the Typescript function into my index.js

**index.js**

```
const business = require('./business');
exports.business.processBusinessSignUp;
```

**business.ts:**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as api from "./api";

import { BusinessFirestoreModel } from "./ts models/business_firestore_model";


module.exports.processBusinessSignUp = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const business_model = new BusinessFirestoreModel(data.fullName, data.businessName, data.email, data.address, data.phone, Date.now());
    return signBusinessUp(business_model);
});

const signBusinessUp = async (business: BusinessFirestoreModel) => {
    const firestoreRef = admin.firestore().collection('pending_business').doc();
    return await api.callFirestoreSet(firestoreRef, business.toJSON());  
}
```

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to run Typescript natively on Cloud Functions?  If so, that's not possible. 
 You need to transpile your TypeScript into regular JavaScript before deploying.

Answer (score 0):

As Brian Burton said You need to transpile your TypeScript into regular JavaScript before deploying if you want to run Typescript natively On Firebase Cloud Function, if you want more information [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript) is the official documentation